# Android - run custom code on settings exit

Tags: android

In my Android application, when the user exits the preference screen, the ui needs to be updated according to the updated preferences. Is there any simple way to do this?

EDIT:
Preferences activity:

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
```

and in the app, a TextView needs to be changed to one of the preferences strings.

Comment: Please put some code what actually you wants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever the UI needs to be updated, those values should be obtained from the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). When you change the preferences simply update your shared preferences values and when you return back to the view (`onResume()`) update your views (by getting the values again from the shared preferences).

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in the activity to be updated and include the code you want to execute in the method onSharedPreferenceChanged(...)

Answer (score 0):

I think its so easy 
From what ever activity you are Starting this activity you shall start it using

```
startActivityForResult(<Your intent>, MY_PREFERENCE);
```

and now you can override `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {

        Log.d("VideoListActivity.onActivityResult ", "Opening");
        switch(requestCode)
        {
        case MY_PREFERENCE:
            switch(resultCode)
            {
            case RESULT_OK:
                // do your stuff

                break;
            case RESULT_CANCELED:
                // do your stuff

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        Log.d("VideoListActivity.onActivityResult ", "Closing");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

and Remember when your job done in your child activity you must set result using this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("isUpdated", true);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```